# Equally resize all children of a Row to fit in their parent

Tags: qml, sailfish-os

I'm trying to put 5 buttons in my window, aligned in a row, and each button should have equal width, while occupying all the available space in the parent. Here's how I'm trying (fails):

```
Row {
      id: toolbar
      width: 300
      height: 80

      Button {
        text: "left"
      }

      Button {
        text: "right"
      }

      Button {
        text: "tab"
      }

      Button {
        text: "home"
      }

      Button {
        text: "end"
      }
}
```

In this example, the `Button` items won't be resized to fit in their parent. I would like to see each `Button` get 1/5 of their parent's width. Obviously, using `Row` isn't enough.

Also, using:

```
width: parent.width / parent.children.count
```

in each Button fails, as `parent.children.count` is `undefined`. One could use `Component.onCompleted` to set the width, when everything is already prepared, but there has to be a better way.

Is there an option of `Row` which enforces a width on its children? Or what other layout option is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnally when doing this I use a Repeater and a ListModel or an array of text so that you can easily know how many `Button` you are going to have and resize them properly

```
ListModel {
    id: modelButtons
    ListElement { buttonText: "left" }
    ListElement { buttonText: "right" }
    ListElement { buttonText: "tab" }
    ListElement { buttonText: "home" }
    ListElement { buttonText: "end" }
}

Row {
    id: toolbar
    width: 300
    height: 80

    Repeater {
        id: repeaterButton
        model: modelButtons
        delegate: Button {
            width: toolbar.width / repeaterButton.model.count
            text: buttonText
        }
    }
}
```